# How to table rate shipping charge apply with specific state?

Tags: checkout, magento2.2, shipping-methods

I have Made one CSV for the table rate shipping method.
When I import CSV in the table rate shipping rate method.
Given this error `We couldn't import this file because of these errors: Please correct Region/State "GJ" in Row #7.`